# Storing the data from text file into mysql table

Tags: python

I have a text file and a MySQL table. the text file look like below.
**new.txt**

```
apple| 3
ball | 4
cat  | 2
```

like this. from this text file I want to store data in the below MySQL table.

```
| query | count | is_prod_ready | time_of_created | last_updated |
```

I want to store apple,ball,cat in the column query, and all the number 3,4,2 in count column. in is_prod_ready  column will be false by default, in time_of_created will take the current time. and last_updated_column will take the update time.

I have already made the table. and i am not able to store all the data into database from the text file. i have tried the below code.

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="9090547207",db="Test")         
cur = con.cursor()
query = 'load data local infile "new.txt" into table data field terminated by "|" lines terminated by "\n" '
cur.execute(query)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

here my data base name is Test and table name is data.

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: @Vikram below o/p Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/snehasish/Desktop/python/new/10_Feb/src/Demo.py", line 5, in <module>
    cur.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",

Comment: line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'field terminated by "|" lines terminated by "\n"\' at line 1')

Comment: I think the fields in the file should enclose in quotes. This is the syntax for your reference, `query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/my/file' INTO TABLE sometable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\\'"
`

Comment: @Vikram it's giving error too. _mysql_exceptions.InternalError: (13, "Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/Test/new.txt' (Errcode: 2)")

Comment: Go to /etc/my.cnf and remove the line that says "local-infile=0", and try to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`

Comment: i am using ubuntu here.

Comment: Please rule out that Python or MySQL is the problem first. Adjust the question and tags then. Also, the full error message belongs to the question, so add it there, please.